# I need to find Vin max(Common Mode) and min(common mode) for given circuit.

Tags: mosfet, amplifier, analog, integrated-circuit, differential

[image]

please let me know how i can proceed with this circuit

Comment: What you should do it **think** about what happens when that maximum or minimum level of the cmm level reached. Consider each case (max, min) separately becuase different things happen for each. What becomes different compared to the circuit's **normal operation**? Once you understand that then determining the values of these voltages becomes easy.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can change it to a current source but be prepared to consider what happens when \$V_{DS}\$ gets too low as this will affect that current: -

[image]

In the picture above the current remains fairly constant above a \$V_{DS}\$ of about 2 volts. Note also that there is a slight slope to the constant current (saturation) area and this may be taken into account in your analysis by using a high value resistor in parallel with the current source.